# Как исправить url mvc php

Tags: php, mvc, url

Я учусь и разрабатываю MVC с нуля, и столкнулся с проблемой УРЛ
Планирую сделать таким

```
хххххх.org/               // Home
хххххх.org/login          // Login
хххххх.org/forgot         // Forgot Password
хххххх.org/reg            // Reg
хххххх.org/126            // Full Post
хххххх.org/126/edit       // Post edit
хххххх.org/cabinet        // User cabinet
хххххх.org/cabinet/edit   // User edit
```

и сейчас моя функция в php написана так

```
class Application
{

    function __construct()
    {

         //------------------------------------------------------
       $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);

         //------------------------------------------------------
       if (empty($url[0])) $url[0] = 'home';
        $url[0] = ucfirst($url[0]);

        //------------------------------------------------------
         $file = CONTROLLER_PATH . $url[0] . '.php';
 
        //------------------------------------------------------
        $controller = new $url[0];

        //------------------------------------------------------
        $controller->loadModel();

        //------------------------------------------------------
        if (isset($url[2])) {
            if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
            } else {
                echo "Метод ехо-виклику з параметром $url[1]($url[2])";
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($url[1])) {
                if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                    $controller->{$url[1]}();
                } else {
                    echo "Помилка виклику методу $url[1]() <br />";
                }
            }
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        $controller->index();
    }
}
```

И мои урлы сейчас стоят так

```
хххххх.org/category/show/126
```

А мне нужно сделать так

```
хххххх.org/126            // Full Post
хххххх.org/126/edit       // Post edit
```

Подскажите, куда мне дальше смотреть в какую сторону писать.

Comment: Это всё очень плохо. Даже не знаешь за что вперёд хвататься. Вся на костылях и соплях. Например, почему не проверяется существование класса? Зачем переменная  $file ? Сама по себе идея автоматического роутинга - кривая. Вместо этого надо прописывать все варианты руками. Тогда и не будет проблемы сделать урл вида хххххх.org/126

Comment: Спасибо! Буду стараться

Comment: Надо все-таки посмотреть как роутинг устроен в настоящих проектах. А не лепить совсем отсебятину. Там код конечно сложный, но хотя бы принцип посмотреть. Каждый роут прописывается отдельно. если есть переменная - она тоже прописывается. Например `$router->addRoute('GET', '/{id:\d+}[/{action}]', [post]);`